# Excel: Finding the difference between dates

Tags: excel, date

I want to find the difference in years between two dates, in two different columns.

1st column: Is the fiscal year shown as 'YYYY', e.g. 2007. This column is formatted as 'General'

2nd column: Is the year a person became CEO shown as 'MM/DD/YYYY'. e.g. 11/28/2011.
This column is formatted as date.

I want to calculate the time a person has been CEO per fiscal years, meaning the difference in the two dates in years. e.g. column 1: 2008 / column 2: 5/25/2004 / difference: 4

Thanks

Comment: So `=A1-year(B1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your year is in A2 and Date is in B2 then try this...

```
=A2-YEAR(B2)
```

And then format the formula cell as General.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
=A1-(RIGHT(B1;4))
```